# Low Profile Floor for Water Underfloor Heating retrofit?

Tags: flooring, heating

I've installed a wet underfloor heating system over my ground floor subfloor and have just been told by a supplier that I can no longer buy the stiff boards that would have gone over the UFH and under the finish layer.  Not sure whether to call this the "upper subfloor" or the "finish floor base layer", but I'd like to find an equally good solution to the original plan, for which the floor layered up like this:

- 3mm LVT.  0.02 m2K/W (0.2 tog)
- 1.5mm thermally conductive underlay.  0.012 m2K/W (0.12 tog)
- 3mm thermally conductive levelling compound.  0.03 m2K/W (0.3 tog)
- 4mm MultiTop boards by Omnie.  0.05 m2K/W (0.5 tog)

Already installed:

- [18mm UFH Extruded Polystyrene overlay boards by Continal](https://www.continal.co.uk/system/slimfix)
- 20mm SUBFLOOR: chipboard / weyroc
- 25mm of EPS insulation
- Concrete slabs

So total height above the UFH would've been 11.5mm and thermal resistance 0.11 m2K/W.  Hard to beat.

XPS UFH overlay boards were the only option because my subfloor isn't very insulated.  This is also why minimising thermal resistance of the layers above the UFH so important.

Omnie's MultiTop boards for the "upper subfloor" were ideal because they have similar strength and thermal resistance to 6mm Plywood, but are thinner, cheaper and flatter.  Omnie suddenly decided they would no longer sell them to me if I didn't buy a full UFH kit from them, but after I'd bought the rest of the floor so that wasn't an option.

I didn't go with Omnie's UFH because Continal's SlimFix 18 boards are stronger (500 KPa compressive strength) and have 100mm pipe spacing qith 12mm pipe giving more heat output and allowing the heat spreading layer to be thinner without risking hotspots.

**So I'm wondering: What flooring can I install to minimise thermal barrier, cost and height?**

Thoughts so far:

1. Thermal conductivity is the top priority, then cost (taking into account install cost and lifespan), then thickness is important but less than the other 2 characteristics.
2. I think wood and engineered wood are out of the question due to cost, and probably also because of thermal resistance.
3. If the solution must have upper subfloor boards over the XPS, can I avoid levelling compound by putting a thicker underlay down?  The original subfloor is pretty flat and the UFH panels are too, I dare say the plywood boards would be the main cause of undulations.  I guess that any height reduction will be lost because I'd have to install thicker click-type planks to handle the undulation.  Also likely thermal conductivity would reduce because the underlay would have to be a sponge so more insulating.
4. I've seen 6mm fibre cement boards for use under tiles (and over wood/chipboard). Their thermals are great but they seem to take less load.  Would they be appropriate over XPS in, say, a living room, and with a non-tile floor on top?
5. Is laying planks straight over UFH pipes, without the intermediate subfloor layer of eg. 6mm plywood a bad idea due to hotspots?
6. Can I lay thin laminate planks (eg. 8mm) straight over the XPS boards (with an overlay)?
7. Could I place thick vinyl planks (6mm?) directly on the XPS boards (with an overlay)?
8. Can I get away with very thin (eg. 1.2mm) underlay if using click-system planks, and let the planks take up most of the undulation?  I guess this would create air pockets under the planks, reducing heat transfer.

Thanks very much!

Comment: Look up the Thermal conductivity of materials. Most wood is bad. Ceramic tiles are good.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @knowitall , but my question relates less to thermal conductivity and more to what makes an acceptably strong floor.  If I wanted to switch to tiles, I'd definitely need to place fibre cement boards over the underfloor heating, and the final height would be a lot more than with LVT.  Tiles don't fit the look I need anyway and there will be cases where the heating is off in winter and vynil/laminate will be more comfortable underfoot.